# Issue in @Twig/Exception/exception_full.html.twig after updating symfony3 with Composer

Tags: symfony

I did the following :

1) I installed a fresh Symfony 3.2.2 version with this command line :  ***php symfony.phar new Symfony3.2.2***

2) I tested the version screen display with this url : http://localhost/Symfony3.2.2/web/app_dev.php/  and it well displays "Welcome to
Symfony 3.2.2 .... "

3) Then I did an update of symfony and all depencies with this command : ***php ../composer.phar update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies***

4) I did not expected it updates anything (since I have installed latest version) but it seems it does, like "Updating twig/twig (v1.31.0 => v2.1.0)" and some few others libs (doctrine collections/annotations/common)

5) Then I retest http://localhost/Symfony3.2.2/web/app_dev.php/  but this times I got this error :

*Twig_Error_Syntax in classes.php line 5280:
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in C:\wamp\www\Symfony3.2.2\var\cache\dev\classes.php on line 5573 and defined") in "@Twig/Exception/exception_full.html.twig".*

6) I have tried to clear cache with command : ***php bin/console cache:clear***  and then retest step 5) but I got same error

So all suggestions are welcome... thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed by myself... it was a PHP issue... after the update, PHP 7 must be used instead PHP 5 (for some libs as Twig I presume like mentioned [here](https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2595)   )

Comment: If your local PHP version is different from the one used on your server you can tell Composer to use a specific PHP version using the `config.platform.php` option: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform